# Why is an empty function !== an empty function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var x = function() {};
var y = function() {};

alert(x === y); // is false;
```

Why is x not equal to y if they are both initialised to the same value?

Comment: Please tag your question with jQuery or whatever framework you are using, so people with the right knowledge come looking to help you.  This is not a generic JavaScript question based on your code example.

Comment: Well, it is a general Javascript question as I'm asking why setting x and y to `function(){}` that `x === y` return false. No framework has anything to do with that. I edited my question so it is simpler. I supppose it has nothing to do with the fact I'm unit testing i guess :)

Comment: Ah, now that is clear and readable.   I would have to search the standards docs.  I am not sure that === on functions actually checks the content rather than the address.   I would never try doing that.  What is it you are actually trying to implement?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: I'm trying to write a unit test. I have a javascript object which has property `onChange`. That object is used in another Javascript file I'm writing tests against. During the initialisation method of that other file I'm testing the `onChange` property is set to a function. Passing a mock of the object I initialised `onChange` in the mock to `function(){}` and wanted to test that after initialise has been executed `onChange` is not still `function(){}`.

Comment: Interesting use case.... I am not a unit tester, being too old for that :-)   According to my quick google, most browsers will give you the function body with `.toString()`.  Could you then not do `if (x.toString() === y.toString()) ... `

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: I was thinking about that but then wondered if using `toString()` in a test is reliable enough. I work around it by initilising `onChange` to `null` instead of `function(){}` and execute the test assertion agaisnt `null` which works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MDN:

> If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal
>   references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in
>   memory.

Clearly, your objects are distinct from each other, and refer to different memory locations. The equals comparison operator checks if both operands refer to the same object, not if they are are replicas.

Consider the fact that `(new Number(1)) != (new Number(1))`, whereas `1 == 1`

Comment: I completly forgot about the `refer to the ame object in memory part` when using `===` on objects. For some reason I assumed that because they both were empty functions it would be different. Even after working with Javascript now for a while I still get cought out by the basics some times. Thank you for the MDN, which I should be remembering by now and the short sample.

Comment: +1. I'm only accepting this answer over the other ones as it was the reference the `same objects in memeory` in the MDN which made the penny drop.

Comment: Glad you got where you needed to go.

Answer (score 8):

When you compare objects in JavaScript, you are checking to see if they are the *same object*, not if they are *identical objects*.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the quick and to-the-point explanation. I was a little confused still to understand the difference between `same` and `identical` until I saw the MDN again. Off course, your explanation it absolutly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because they aren't the same function object. The comparator does not look at the function body.

Answer (score 2):

The ECMA standard gives [some precise rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) on how strict equality works in JavaScript. Basically, as @Quentin said, if you are comparing two objects (other than Number, String, Boolean, null or undefined), it only returns true if they are the same object. That is not the case here.

Consider this code:

```
var x = function() {};
var y = function() {};
x.something = "this is x";
y.something = "this is not x";
alert(x.something === y.something);
```

This will give `false`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Spec-11.9.6](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6):

***The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm***

> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or
> false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1.If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
>
> 2.If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
>
> 3.If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>
> ...
>
> **7.Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.**